# How to solve conditional expectation problem?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Two life insurance policies, each with a death benefit of $10,000$ and a one-time premium of $500$,
are sold to a couple, one for each person. The policies will expire at the end of the tenth year. The
probability that only the wife will survive at least ten years is $0.025$, the probability that only the
husband will survive at least ten years is $0.01$, and the probability that both of them will survive
at least ten years is $0.96$.

What is the expected excess of premiums over claims, given that the husband survives at least ten
years?

The answer my professor provided is: $896.9072165...$

---

I am having trouble deriving this answer.

My method was as follows:

$\frac{0*(0.96)+10,000*(0.01)+10,000*(0.025)}{0.01+0.96}=\frac{350}{0.97}=360.82847...+500=860.8247423...$

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

No, you have confused the first part.

P(wife survives | husband has survived) $=\dfrac{0.96}{0.96+0.01} = \dfrac{96}{97}$

Expected excess of premiums over claims $= \left(\dfrac{96}{97}\cdot 500  - \dfrac1{97}\cdot9500\right)$   + 500